# better way to write trino query selecting multiple date ranges

Tags: presto, trino

Is there a more elegant way to write this trino query whereby I can just utilize the timeline_before_and_after table and not have to repeat the time intervals?

```
    with locations_that_are_being_deployed AS 
(
  select * from (
     VALUES 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'
  ) as t (location)
),
timeline_before_and_after AS (
  select * from (
     VALUES ('before', '20240101', '20240104'),
            ('during', '20240105', '20240106'),
            ('after', '20240107', '20240109')
  ) as t (time_category, startdt, enddt)
),
logs_we_care_about AS (
  select *, 
         case when (ts_date >= '20240101' and ts_date <= '20240104') then 1 else 0 end before,
         case when (ts_date >= '20240105' and ts_date <= '20240106') then 1 else 0 end during,
         case when (ts_date >= '20240107' and ts_date <= '20240109') then 1 else 0 end after
  from
  mylogtable f
  join locations_that_are_being_deployed p
  on p.location = f.location
  where 
       (
          (ts_date >= '20240101' and ts_date <= '20240104') OR
          (ts_date >= '20240105' and ts_date <= '20240106') OR 
          (ts_date >= '20240107' and ts_date <= '20240109')
       )
)
select * from logs_we_care_about
```